# Select with update statement sap hana

Tags: sql, hana

I'm trying to combine select and update in one statement

In select I'm trying to find what is the current Fiscal year fiscal period based on table `"month_dim"` and by using current date. its running fine since it has corresponding values. But I need to pass values from select to update statement to same table to update values of `CY`,`PY` and `YTD`. Currently in update statements I'm doing hard coding and have 3 separate update statements. it will good if it can be combined in one as well.

```
select fiscal_period, fiscal_year from "schema_name"."month_dim" where date_sql = current_date
```

update statements are below:-

```
UPDATE "Schema_name"."month_dim" SET

  YTD = case when fiscal_period <= '1'

       then 'Y' else 'N' end;
UPDATE " Schema_name "."month_dim" SET

    CY = case when fiscal_year >= '2021'

       then 'Y' else 'N' end;
UPDATE " Schema_name "."month_dim" SET

    PY = case when fiscal_year <= '2021'

       then 'Y' else 'N' end;
```

Please help

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for? :

```
DO
BEGIN
DECLARE FISCALPERIOD NVARCHAR(3); 
DECLARE FISCALYEAR NVARCHAR(4);

    SELECT 
            fiscal_period, fiscal_year 
        INTO fiscalperiod, fiscalyear 
    FROM 
            schema_name.month_dim
    WHERE 
           date_sql = current_date;

    UPDATE schema_name.month_dim
    SET
        YTD = CASE
                  WHEN fiscal_period <= :fiscalperiod THEN 'Y'
                  ELSE 'N'
              END
      , CY = CASE
                 WHEN fiscal_year >= :fiscalyear THEN 'Y'
                 ELSE 'N'
             END
      , PY = CASE
                 WHEN fiscal_year <= :fiscalyear THEN 'Y'
                 ELSE 'N'
             END;
END;
```

Comment: Thanks Ehsan, I want to read Fiscal_period and Fiscal_year from same table month_dim by passing current date. And in update statement rather then hard coding of "1" and "2021" I shall be using  Fiscal_period and Fiscal_year from select statement.

Comment: anyone help please

Comment: @Rubane I might got some syntax error , but you got the idea

Comment: I got idea but..update statement throwing systax error and I'm unable to resolve not sure what wrong we are doing? do we need brackets for update?

Comment: I think we need to put Do begin and end for declare and select not sure about update statement?

Comment: see I posted changed code..do you've idea why getting error for update statement?

Comment: Could not execute 'DO BEGIN DECLARE FISCALPERIOD Varchar(3); DECLARE FISCALYEAR Varchar(4); SELECT FISCAL_PERIOD, ...'
SAP DBTech JDBC: [257]: sql syntax error: incorrect syntax near "UPDATE": line 15 col 1 (at pos 224)

Comment: @Rubane remove " ( double quote)  from table names , that might be the issue , SAP has good docs on the syntax and also if you have access to HANA data explorer you can test out your code easily

Comment: same issue even after removing the double quotes.....if I run update statement it runs fine. But not with the select may be something is missing...

Comment: @Rubane how about missing ; at the end of update statement? I tested query above in SAP explorer and It works

Comment: The posted solution code missed the first `DECLARE` statement. In its current form, the statement should work fine.

Comment: is there a sample code I can convert this in an stored procedure?

Comment: @Rubane https://help.sap.com/viewer/7c78579ce9b14a669c1f3295b0d8ca16/Cloud/en-US/20d467407519101484f190f545d54b24.html?q=procedure